# how can I calculate the sum according to the set of offer

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate the sum of the charges that will be grouped according to the User and the series of services. And I wonder, how I can joining the "charge" to user table?

I have a user table :

| u_id | offer_1 | offer_2 | offer_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 11 |  |  |
| 101 |  | 12 | 13 |
| 101 |  | 12 |  |
| 101 |  |  | 13 |
| 201 | 22 | 32 | 33 |

A transaction table:

| u_id | offer_id | charge |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 11 | 150 |
| 101 | 12 | 150 |
| 101 | 13 | 200 |
| 201 | 22 | 300 |
| 201 | 32 | 100 |
| 201 | 33 | 45 |

My expected table is:

| u_id | offer_1 | offer_2 | offer_3 | charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 11 |  |  | 150 |
| 101 |  | 12 | 13 | 350 |
| 101 |  | 12 |  | 150 |
| 101 |  |  | 13 | 200 |
| 201 | 22 | 32 | 33 | 445 |

I tried standard sum() function:

```
select u.u_id,u.offer_1,u.offer_2,u.offer_3,sum(t.charge)
from user u
left join transaction t on u.offer_1 = t.offer_id or u.offer_2 = t.offer_id  or u.offer_2 = t.offer_id 
group by u.u_id,u.offer_1,u.offer_2,u.offer_3
```

Can you help me?

Comment: When you post here, you should make it as easy for us to test our proposals as possible. For that, tables shouldn't be shown in a nice-looking format (although that doesn't hurt - as an addition, not an instead-of), but as `create table` and `insert` statements; or, alternatively, as a `with` clause: `with user(u_id, offer_1, offer_2, offer_3) as ( select ... )` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data (note I added a row with all `null` offers in the first table, to test correctness for that case too):

```
create table user_tbl (u_id, offer_1, offer_2, offer_3) as
    select 101,   11, null, null from dual union all
    select 101, null,   12,   13 from dual union all
    select 101, null,   12, null from dual union all
    select 101, null, null,   13 from dual union all
    select 201,   22,   32,   33 from dual union all
    select 201, null, null, null from dual
;

create table transactions (u_id, offer_id, change) as
    select 101, 11, 150 from dual union all
    select 101, 12, 150 from dual union all
    select 101, 13, 200 from dual union all
    select 201, 22, 300 from dual union all
    select 201, 32, 100 from dual union all
    select 201, 33,  45 from dual
;
```

Query and output:

```
with
  prep (rn, u_id, offer_1, offer_2, offer_3, o1, o2, o3) as (
    select rownum, u_id, offer_1, offer_2, offer_3, offer_1, offer_2, offer_3
    from   user_tbl
  )
select u_id, offer_1, offer_2, offer_3, nvl(sum(change), 0) as change
from   prep
unpivot include nulls (offer_id for col in (o1, o2, o3))
left outer join transactions using (u_id, offer_id)
group by u_id, offer_1, offer_2, offer_3, rn
;

      U_ID    OFFER_1    OFFER_2    OFFER_3     CHANGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       101         11                              150
       101                    12                   150
       101                    12         13        350
       101                               13        200
       201         22         32         33        445
       201                                           0
```

Unpivoting brings the data to a more familiar form, with one row per combination of `u_id` and "offer". The join is an outer join for two reasons: both because the unpivoting may generate `null` offers, and because a non-`null` offer may not have a match in the `transactions` table. (For that matter, a `u_id` may not have a match there either.) The rest is what you would expect - the outer join and the aggregation - and using `nvl` in the main select, assuming the `change` should be shown as zero (rather than null) when a row shows no actual offers.